# C# DataTable - How to set a column to value without for loop?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable called dataTable that has two columns Col1 and Col2 and it contains five rows all initialized to null. How would I set the values in Col1 and Col2 to "1" and "2" respectively without using a for loop or foreach loop for each DataRow?

Comment: why do you need it? and what have you done so far?

Comment: dt.Columns["Col1"].DefaultValue = "1"; dt.Columns["Col2"].DefaultValue = "2";

Comment: @viveknuna this will affect the rows added **after** you set the DefaultValue. If the rows are already in the datatable they will not be changed by this settings

Comment: dt.Columns["col1"].Expression = "'1'"; dt.Columns["col2"].Expression = "'2'";

Comment: There is no "the best" way to implement features but OP's demand is definitely not good at any extent.

Comment: You can use a while loop :). On a serious note - you are asking how you can set a number of variables without setting each of them. It is impossible. Even if you manage to do this in one line of code this just means that the loop exists somewhere deeper in that code.

Comment: There is no way, but more importantly why would you want to avoid loop? There are some languages where this could be done seemingly without loop, but and the end of the day its still a loop. Even  using the multiple assignment statement, while definitely not a loop will at the end of the day be almost equivalent (in most situations, Im sure someone could point out one where they would be a material difference)

Answer (score 0):

Use 10 assignment statements.  No loop required.